# Port status is always down and cant open UMAD port

Tags: linux, suse, infiniband

I have newly installed ofed-1.5-3 on following machine :

SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 1

Our admin has installed CX354A card (MCX354A-FCBT) card on the machine.
$ lspci | grep -i mel
04:00.0 Network controller: Mellanox Technologies Device 1003

(Question 1: I dont know if this output of lspci is correct or not, I suspect
it to be though, but dont know how do I get the correct output.)

After I installed ofed package through ./mlnxofedinstall script :

Output of ofed_info | head -1 :
MLNX_OFED_LINUX-1.5.3-3.1.0 (OFED-1.5.3-3.1.0):

The installation was successful, and openibd did load all the required
modules/drivers. 
$ service openibd status

HCA driver loaded

Configured IPoIB devices:
ib0 ib1

Currently active IPoIB devices:

The following OFED modules are loaded:

rdma_ucm
  ib_srp
  rdma_cm
  ib_addr
  ib_ipoib
  mlx4_core
  mlx4_ib
  mlx4_en
  ib_mthca
  ib_uverbs
  ib_umad
  ib_ucm
  ib_sa
  ib_cm
  ib_mad
  ib_core
  iw_cxgb3
  iw_nes

Output of hca_self_test.ofed

---- Performing Adapter Device Self Test ----
Number of CAs Detected ................. 1
PCI Device Check ....................... PASS
Kernel Arch ............................ x86_64
Host Driver Version .................... MLNX_OFED_LINUX-1.5.3-3.1.0
(OFED-1.5.3-3.1.0): 2.6.32.12-0.7-default
Host Driver RPM Check .................. PASS
Firmware on CA #0 VPI .................. v2.10.700
Firmware Check on CA #0 (VPI) .......... NA
    REASON: NO required fw version
Host Driver Initialization ............. PASS
Number of CA Ports Active .............. 0
Port State of Port #1 on CA #0 (VPI)..... DOWN (InfiniBand)
Port State of Port #2 on CA #0 (VPI)..... DOWN (InfiniBand)
Error Counter Check on CA #0 (VPI)...... PASS
Kernel Syslog Check .................... PASS
Node GUID on CA #0 (VPI) ............... 00:02:c9:03:00:f9:ed:e0
------------------ DONE ---------------------

Question 2: Now when I tried ibstatus or ibv_devinfo, I see the port status as
PORT_DOWN. While I read in docs is that it should be in INIT state. My question
is how do I   get this to INIT state. 
$ ibv_devinfo

hca_id: mlx4_0
        transport:                      InfiniBand (0)
        fw_ver:                         2.10.700
        node_guid:                      0002:c903:00f9:ede0
        sys_image_guid:                 0002:c903:00f9:ede3
        vendor_id:                      0x02c9
        vendor_part_id:                 4099
        hw_ver:                         0x0
        board_id:                       MT_1090120019
        phys_port_cnt:                  2
                port:   1
                        state:                  PORT_DOWN (1)
                        max_mtu:                2048 (4)
                        active_mtu:             2048 (4)
                        sm_lid:                 0
                        port_lid:               0
                        port_lmc:               0x00
                        link_layer:             IB

```
            port:   2
                    state:                  PORT_DOWN (1)
                    max_mtu:                2048 (4)
                    active_mtu:             2048 (4)
                    sm_lid:                 0
                    port_lid:               0
                    port_lmc:               0x00
                    link_layer:             IB
```

When I tried following command I got error :

$ ibportstate  -G 0x0002c90300f9ede0 1 query/enable/disable
ibwarn: [9318] mad_rpc_open_port: can't open UMAD port ((null):0)
ibportstate: iberror: failed: Failed to open '(null)' port '0'

Question 3: Didnt get why I got this error, or how do I get rid of it. Any help
will be very appreciated.

Please let me know if you need more info.

Thanks

Comment: Old question, but just in case somebody cares... Are you doing this as root?  Trying to query or set infiniband status from a regular user account will cause a "can't open UMAD port" error.

Answer (score 1):

The port status in ibv_devinfo will be down until you connect this node to either another node or infiniband switch with infiniband cable. From modules it looks like you got all the necessary things setup, just missing another node to talk to. As soon as you connect it to another node, you should be able to see state changed to PORT_INIT and link speed etc populated.